# QML canvas rotate ellipse

Tags: html, canvas, qml

I'm drawing an ellipse on a QML canvas, and I'd like to be able to rotate it. Is there any way to do this apart from `context.rotate(angle)`? As I understand, this will rotate the entire canvas. Is there some way of rotating only a subpath?

I was a tad surprised that the ellipse is defined by a center along with width and height, rather than by two focal points. That would have made things a lot easier.

Comment: Can't you save the state of the context, apply the transformation for the ellipse, draw the ellipse and then restore the state ?
Like described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#A_rotate_example

Comment: I don't think so. "The current path is NOT part of the drawing state." - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#save-method.

Comment: I fail to see how that is a problem. Do you have a code example ?

Comment: Another example [here](http://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch07/index.html#transformation): as you see transformation sum up and with `resetTransform()` you can remove all of them and start painting other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GrecKo's comment is absolutely correct, just added the code in case someone else needs a summary. Moving the coordinate system (translate) to put the origin at the center of the ellipse, then rotating and moving it back to its original position.

```
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
 context.save()
 context.translate(ellipse.center.x, ellipse.center.y)
 context.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * degrees)
 context.translate(-ellipse.center.x, -ellipse.center.y)
 context.restore()
 canvas.requestPaint()
```